# directing to new page with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-bootstrap

I am getting list via  Api for my project. I am able to list them in my home page. To see more detail about each item  I clicked them. it shows on the main page not in a new page. I want to display new page. And When I clicked the logo in a navbar I want to go the home page again. How can I achieve that? Thanks for your time.

this is my  app.js

```
return (
    <div className="main-bg">
        <div className='container'>
                    <div>
                    <Navbar/>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row'>                       
                    <PokemonList
                            pokemons={pokemons}
                            handleFavouritesClick={addFavouritePokemon}
                            favouriteComponent={AddFavourites}
                        />                  
                <Switch>        
                <Route path="/pokemon/:id" component={PokemonDetail} /> 
                </Switch>   
               </div>       
           </div>
     </div>
  );
```

this is my detailpage.

```
<div className="col-md-3 my-5">
        <div className="card-outer w-100 p-2 rounded text-center">
            <h5 className="card-header">{pokemons}</h5> 
            </div>                      
        </div>              
     </div>
```

this is the part where I click and  is supposed to direct me to detail page

```
      **<StyledLink to={`pokemon/${pokemon.id}`}>**
                    <Card>
                        <div className="w-100 p-2 rounded text-center card-outer">
                        <h5 className="card-header">{pokemon.id}</h5> 
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        </div>
                    </Card> 
                </StyledLink>
```

Finally this my index.js ``

```
  import React from 'react';
     import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './App';
    import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
      <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
   </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: I think the solution is to include the pokemon list as a route, same way as pokemonDetail, so that the Switch component wraps both.

Comment: I see that,  How can  I achieve that What should I write as path and How can I include these in a route  pokemons={pokemons}
                            handleFavouritesClick={addFavouritePokemon}
                            favouriteComponent={AddFavourites} @Nacho